# Why is path not working in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, webkit, native

I am learning to write an iOS-native webkit app. In Xcode 3.x, I have index.html distributed in Resources folder and the following code works correctly:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];  
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    if (htmlData)
    {  
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
        NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];
        NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:path];
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath]]];
    }
}
```

The index.html is not loaded when I create a project on Xcode 4.2. I have the index.html in the "Supporting Files" folder. Have I missed something? Please help.

Thanks

Adrian

Comment: Sorry for the question. The function should be viewDidLoad, not viewDidUnload.

Comment: You can post this as the answer and mark it as correct to close the question

Comment: Sorry. This is my first post here but I'm learning. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: That's not a problem. The intention of my comment was to help you learn. I've upvoted your answer too since it was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my carelessness. The function should be viewDidLoad, not viewDidUnload.

Thanks.